# Can't Install ImageMagick on Centos using Yum

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, php, imagemagick

I am trying to install ImageMagick on my dedicated-virtual Centos server for use with PHP.

1. I first ran the following commands successfully:

   ```
   # yum install gcc php-devel php-pear
   # yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel
   ```
2. Then, I ran this command:

   ```
   # pecl install imagick
   ```
3. After I ran it, I got this error:

   > downloading imagick-3.1.2.tgz ... Starting to download
   >   imagick-3.1.2.tgz (94,657 bytes) .....................done: 94,657
   >   bytes 15 source files, building running: phpize Configuring for: PHP
   >   Api Version:         20100412 Zend Module Api No:      20100525 Zend
   >   Extension Api No:   220100525 shtool at
   >   '/var/tmp/imagick/build/shtool' does not exist or is not executable.
   >   Make sure that the file exists and is executable and then rerun this
   >   script.
   >
   > ERROR: `phpize' failed
4. So, I google'd it and found that I should do this:

   > If you see this error, it most likely means the server’s /tmp
   >   directory does not allow executables to run.  Set a different
   >   temporary directory on a filesystem on which you can execute binaries.
   >   For instance: pear config-set temp_dir /root/tmp
   >
   > Then re-run:  pecl upgrade-all

   Ref.
   https://opdk.info/faqs/error-shown-during-install-shtool-%E2%80%98vartmpimagickbuildshtool%E2%80%99-does-not-exist-or-not-executable
5. So, I created a new directory in my root and changed the PEAR config
   variable like so:

   ```
   # mkdir rw ../tmp2
   # pear config-set temp_dir ../tmp2
   ```

**But, now, after trying to install again I get this error:**

```
# pecl install imagick
downloading imagick-3.1.2.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.1.2.tgz (94,657 bytes)
.....................done: 94,657 bytes
ERROR: SECURITY ERROR: file config.m4 (installed to ../tmp2/imagick/config.m4) contains 
parent directory reference ..
```

How can I fix this?  I just want to install ImageMagick.

Comment: Have you tried this with absolute path reference to temporary directory, instead of using a relative one?

Comment: Thanks so much.  That actually solved it!  You can post an answer if you'd like, and I'll accept

Comment: @SamiLaine By the way, would it hurt to leave `pear config-set temp_dir ../tmp2` at `tmp2` instead of whatever the default is?